# What is difference between npm install bootstrap and npm install bootstrap --save

Tags: npm

Q.1 if we use below command how many places will be affected in angular project

npm install bootstrap

Q.2 what is difference if we use above command with --save

npm install bootstrap --save

Comment: There is no difference for now. Both will add it to dependencies section of the package.json

Comment: How many places of angular project will be affected if we use  npm install package

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Running 'npm install bootstrap' command will download the latest version of bootstrap and install in subfolder './node_module' folder.

Q2. Running install --save bootstrap will do same as above but will update package.json by adding entry under dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Before npm 5.0.0 they were different but now there is no difference.

> Before version 5.0.0

1. `npm install bootstrap --save` would download the latest version of bootstrap and add it to your `dependencies` in `package.json` file.
2. `npm install bootstrap` would download the latest version of bootstrap but it would not add it in `dependencies` in  `package.json` file.

> After version [5.0.0](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500)

there is no difference between both commands. As it was `--save` was made default so with or without `--save` it would add it in `dependencies` in `package.json`

> In addition, there are the complementary options `--save-dev` and `--save-optional` which save the package under `devDependencies` and `optionalDependencies`, respectively. This is useful when installing development-only packages, like `grunt` or your testing library.